# How to open wifi settings on Nook/NookColor

Tags: android, wifi, nook

My app needs active wifi connection. I added button "Go to wifi settings" with this code

```
Intent settings = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
settings.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(settings);
```

It is works perfect on 95% of devices. But on Nook color I have error

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.settings.WIFI_SETTINGS flg=0x10000000 }

How to open wifi settings on Nook/Nook color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Summary**:
1-Find desired activity's complete name in Nook.
2-Set your intent classname with it.
3-Start your intent.
**Details**:
1-a:Connect your device to PC that you are developing your project.
1-b:Open `Hierarchy view perspective` of eclipse and then open `Windows` in that perspective.
1-c:Open your desired Activity manually in device.(home -> setting -> ...)
1-d:It may be need to do refresh on `Windows` in perspective.
1-e:All existing Activities with their complete name and package name must be seen in `Windows` in `Hierarchy view perspective`.
[image]
For example,here my desired activity name is:`com.android.settings.WirelessSettings` and it's package name is `com.android.settings`.

I hope this snippet code help you to continue:

```
b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.android.settings",
        "com.android.settings.WirelessSettings");
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

For more details on `Calling App from another` you can see this questions: [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674391/calling-an-app-from-another-app) - [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977243/launching-external-application-from-my-app)

Comment: 10tx! The correct line: `settings.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.wifi.Settings_Wifi_Settings");`